# Is my guppy pregnant if so how long has she been and how long has she got left of the pregnancy?

Tags: guppies

Yesterday I got a female guppy from a pet shop and when I put her in my tank I realised how much fatter she was compared to my other females is she pregnant if so how long has she been pregnant and if ur really clever how long has she got left of the pregnancy?[image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

yes your guppy is pregnant,judging from the first picture it is less than a week before it gives birth.

a guppy is pregnant for five weeks.
they are pregnant all the time.

what you see is the dark spot around the anal area of your fish is the babies.

to see how far the pregnancy have come you look at the spot in the anal area of your fish,in the start of pregnancy it is light red/pink but as the pregnancy progress it gets darker and when it gets allmost black the babies are ready to get born.

the babies are born whitout color,they are grey or yellow when born.

the dark spot on the female is actually the eyes of the babies visible thru the skin of the mother.

a single guppy can give birth to more than 20 babies at a time but the normal is 6-15,so take care you might end up with a lot of guppies.

guppies will eat their young so you shuld get a breeding tank if you want to keep the babies.

the longer you wait to put the guppy in the breeding tank the less stress for the guppy,but when the spot on your guppy is allmost black it is time to put it in the breeding tank.

Comment: We had some guppies and never had a birth tank. But if there are enough plants to hide, some of the babies will survive. So we never had to rebuy guppies, even when some died due to natural age.

Comment: Thanks also when should I put her in my breeding tank ?

Comment: i put this information in the answer now.if you have lots of plants or other hiding places you will probably not need a breeding tank.